# Cannot add target group to NLB

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I created an AWS NLB and I created a new Target Group during NLB setup for TLS / Port 443.

Now I want to add another Target Group for TCP Port 80 and I created a new Target Group.

When trying to register the Target Group under "Listeners" the Target Group for TCP Port 80 is greyed out:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Another solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169283/aws-create-listener-from-console-all-target-groups-are-greyed-out

Answer (score 16):

I had this, and the load balancer UI did not make it easy to edit existing target groups, so the easiest fix was to delete the old target group and start over, **looking closely at the protocol.** The Add Target Group page has a protocol selector that defaults to HTTP & port 80, and it is intuitive to leave it that way, but **you need TCP** or whichever protocol the balancer is going to forward.

[image: screenshot of AWS Load Balancer's Add Target Group form, with protocol/port selectors]

This is because the Network Load Balancer operates at a lower, more flexible level (layer 4 + TLS termination) and only supports TCP / UDP / TLS. On the Add Listener page, you will have the same Protocol and Port fields, and the new target group will be allowed as long as the Protocol matches. If you select a target group there and then change to a different protocol, the page will show an error like "TCP_UDP listeners cannot forward traffic to TCP target groups. You must select a compatible target group or change the listener protocol."

[image: screenshot of the protocol/port selectors in AWS Load Balancer's Add Listener form]

Answer (score 0):

ALB/NLB by design allows a target group to be used by a single ALB/NLB only, you would have already used the `*nlb-route-http` target group in a different NLB, can you post status of targets under `*nlb-route-http` if there is healthy/unhealthy instances then its already being used and you won't be able to re-attach it. 
Either remove from existing NLB or create a new target group.

Comment: Trying to configure a similar scenario and having the same issue.
I have created a new target group. I want to assign it as the default target group for our port 80 listener on our existing NLB.

Since NLB's cannot manipulate headers I am attempting to configure a separate target group to handle port 80 traffic. Its job is to only redirect to https.

When I go into my NLB and select the listener to change the default TargeGroup I can see the new Target Group I created however it is greyed out and I cannot select it.

Comment: @JohnMorrison we can use the newly created target group, if its not already being used in another in *LB, so your newly created grp should appear, may be am getting your comment wrong. i confirmed this behaviour with AWS as well that time.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem even when I chose TCP as the Target Group protocol.

That is, I created a target group first, then separately created an application load balancer and the target group didn't appear in the "Select a target group" drop down menu.

The only way I got it to work was to create a target group of type "IP addresses", then select it in the target group list and choose "Associate with New Load Balancer" from the Actions menu.

Only then did the Target Group appear in the "Select a target group" dropdown menu.